# Is there a theorum on function translatability?

Tags: functions, logic

I have an intuition, that any pure function that is written in a turing complete language can be translated exactly to any other turing complete language. That is, for every pair of turing complete languages A and B there exists a function translateFromAtoB which takes a pure function written in language A and translates it perfectly into language B.

Am I correct? Is there a common name for such a theorum?

Comment: "Church's Thesis" ;/

Comment: except when $A$ can additionally compute even some non-computable functions ... :)